# Непонятный NaN в js

Tags: javascript, nan

есть следующий код на js

```js
var AllDate = {
 curdate: new Date(),
 begining: new Date ("2018-06-23T00:00:00.000"),
 deferense: function () {
  return Math.trunc((this.curdate - this.begining)/1000/60/60/24);
 }(),
};
```

Но по итогу мы имеем `AllDate.deferense = NaN;`

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function () {
    return Math.trunc((this.curdate - this.begining)/1000/60/60/24);
}()
```

Это самовызывающаяся анонимная функция, которая никакого отношения к контексту объекта во время выполнения иметь не будет. Лучше всего в данном случае использовать геттер

```
var AllDate = {
  curdate: new Date(),
  begining: new Date ("2018-06-23T00:00:00.000"),
  get deferense() {
    return Math.trunc((this.curdate - this.begining)/1000/60/60/24);
  },
};

console.log(AllDate.deferense)
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вас метод `deferense` запускается тогда, когда еще объект не создался. Как вариант можете это действие разделить на две части или вызвать с помощью `call` с передачей объекта в виде контекста.

```js
var AllDate = {
  curdate: new Date(),
  begining: new Date("2018-06-23T00:00:00.000"),
  deferense: function() {
    //console.log(this);
    return Math.trunc((this.curdate - this.begining) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
  }.call(AllDate),
};
console.log(AllDate);
```

Comment: undefined undefined

Comment: Кстати, если после всего AllData вставить строчку console.log(AllDate.curdate, AllDate.begining); то выведутся нормальные верные даты

Comment: @igor_bal, поправил ответ, пробуйте